# Rails delete objects from a has_many :through relation, based on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class User
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, through: :likes
end

class Artist
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :likes
end

class Like
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

I would like to delete User <-> Artist associations (and **not** associated objects themselves), based on a given condition. I tried:

```
user.artists.where(...).delete_all
```

but artist objects have been removed as well, not only the associations.

If I don't supply a condition:

```
user.artists.delete_all
```

only the associations are removed, not the artist objects themselves.

So, how can I remove associations from a `has_many :through` relation, based on a condition?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that thinking outside the box did the trick in this situation.

By applying the conditions directly on the join model, I could delete only the associations:

```
Like.where(...).delete_all
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `joins` method with adding conditions

```
user.likes.joins(:artist).where(artists: {...}).delete_all
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins

---

If you want destroy objects and their dependencies, use `destroy_all` method instead of `delete_all`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all

Comment: Destroys the records matching conditions by instantiating each record and calling its destroy method. Each object’s callbacks are executed (including :dependent association options).

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want! I only want to remove the associations. I've edited the question to make this clearer.